# Global Admin can't access SharePoint Admin

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, central-administration

I've set one Office 365 account to Global Administrator.

When that user tries to access SharePoint Admin page (domain-admin.sharepoint.com), he gets "Access Denied".

What could be the problem?

Comment: What license does that Account have?

Comment: He has Office 365 Business Premium license assigned. For example, I have another user, who does not have any license, is global administrator as well, and have full access to everything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below steps

1. Provide a Global Admin user in SharePoint Online license.
2. waiting for Azure AD to be synchronized with SharePoint Online …
3. login to O365 portal and go to the SharePoint Admin Center.
4. then remove SharePoint Online license for the Global Administrator.
5. waiting for Azure AD to be synchronized with SharePoint Online …
6. and now Global Admin user go to SharePoint Admin Center without a license.

   - See more with detail at: [Global Admin can’t access SharePoint Admin Center](http://www.viding.se/?p=48#sthash.kEnRX4RO.dpuf)

If above did not resolve then you have to contact the Customer Support. 
[Can't access Office 365 online apps](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cant-access-office-365-online-apps/994f4685-5dab-4837-b012-8176ae52eea9)

Comment: Thanks! I was on the 5th step apparently, I've waited for a sync and now the user has access to it :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.  At the same time I had the issue I was testing adding a proxy address that was a duplicate of another user's email.  I was hoping it would work since the user didn't have any type of MS license that included email.  That user only had a Power BI per capacity license and a fabric license.

Once I removed the duplicate proxy address and synced our active directory to azure, I was able to access the sharepoint admin center.